# "these clues four" VS "these four clues"

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

> Choose, unless you wish to stay here forevermore
>    To help you in your choice, we give you **these clues four**
>   First, however slyly the poison tries to hide
>   You will always find some on nettle wine's left side
>   ; Second, ...*

Is there any difference between **these clues four** and **these four clues**? Why is "**these clues four**" used instead of **these four clues**?

-- Excerpted from Harry Potter.

Comment: I have edited your question to separate the lines: you can now see that it is a poem and the word order has been changed so that **four** rhymes with **evermore**. This sort of thing s normal in poems, and does not change the meaning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about rhyming in poetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.
You are given four clues.
The unusual word order is to produce the rhyme.